# Check User login status in every five seconds

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create an application in PHP where admin can suspend the account access of website of a user (after login) through his admin panel. I am using a column named Session in user table to store Current Session Id and matching with current session id with database value (which is stored at the time of login) but gone blank as Admin suspend the access. Below is my code will someone help me in doing same actually it's not working. I am using AJAX and PHP.

```
var currentSessionValue = <?php echo $myDB->get(USERS,'session','id='.$_SESSION['UserId']); ?>;
// pseudo code
setInterval(checkVariableValue, 5000);
function checkVariableValue() {
    alert(currentSessionValue);
     $.ajax({
        url: 'checkLoginStatus.php',
        success: function(newVal) {
            if (newVal == currentSessionValue);
                alert('You are Logged out by Administrator.');
                window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 1000);
            }
     });
}
```

Comment: Instead of overloading your server with all these ban checks, can't you do the check whenever a user tries to actually _do_ something?

Comment: Even alert is not working from given code. Mike

Answer (score 0):

Making a database call every five seconds for each user that is logged in seems like a bad idea. Depending on how many users you expect to have, this could lead to a major performance hit.

Instead, it might be a better idea to check the database whenever your users actually attempt to do anything that hits the server. So each time they go to a different page or each time content is loaded via AJAX, etc. you can perform this check.

And I'm not sure what you're doing with session IDs, but if you're going to hit the database anyways, why not just store an extra column in your `users` table (call it `suspended` or something) that holds the status of whether or not the user's access is suspended?

If that column is set to `0`, they're good. But if it's set to `1`, then log the user out and don't let them log back in (or do, up to you).

If you don't want to deny them from logging back in, then just either set the value back to `0` before you log them out or when they log back in.

Comment: actually i have only 5 users and want to stop unauthorized access to my files they are using after logging in. But I liked your idea of checking column value instead of Session

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you wanted to write:

```
if (newVal == currentSessionValue) {
```

instead of

```
if (newVal == currentSessionValue);
```

I think also that you may even wanted to use `newVal != currentSessionValue` instead...

Comment: Sorry, it was same actually I tested the code and use alert to print Current Session but not getting success.